# Add WebPart to SharePoint Page layout

Tags: web-part, page-layout, publishing-site, design-manager

I am new to SharePoint customization. I want to add a webpart to an existing page layout. I found this tutorial at msdn but I don't understand how to add the real webpart to the page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862341.aspx

My understanding says that I have to add the markup from the msdn article to the page layout. But this is only a zone where I can add the webpart.

How do I add the real webpart to the zone? I clicked around the Design-Manager a little bit but did not found anything where I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862341.aspx) explains only to place how you can place the dynamic Web Part zone in that page layout.

Once you save and select that page layout in any of your publishing page, you will be able to add a web part in edit page section. Read [this article](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Add-snippets-in-Page-layout-using-design-manager).

If you want to place your custom static Web Part zone in page layout, Though there are different ways to do this you can place the static web part code inside `<ZoneTemplate>` tag.

Also adding Web Part zone varies as per the SharePoint version, so make sure you tag it.